# np.append only giving last value appended?

Tags: python, numpy, append

In the code below I tried to use `np.append` but it only gives me the last value appended in the loop.

I have two nested for loops (one runs with index `i`, the other one with `k`). Now I want to exercise a certain function for different indices and I want the outcomes to be summarized in one array. So that each line in the array contains the outcome for one index.

Here a minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,2,1)
b = np.arange(3,5,1)
c = np.array([])

for i in range(0,2,1):
    for k in range(0,2,1):
        c = np.append(a[i],b[k])
print(c)
```

The outcome is `[1 4]`. But I want one single vector `c` containing `([0 3][0 4][1 3][1 4])`

Comment: Is using `numpy/append ` mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating 1d array instead of 2d. and in [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)  you have to pass current array and appending elements and it will return a new array.

```
a = np.arange(0,2,1)
b = np.arange(3,5,1)
c = np.empty(shape=[0, 2])

for i in range(0,2,1):
    for k in range(0,2,1):
        c = np.append(c,[[a[i],b[k]]],axis=0)
        
print(c)
```

**Outptut:**

```
[[0. 3.]
 [0. 4.]
 [1. 3.]
 [1. 4.]]
```

Comment: @Felix Note:. np.append is slower compared to python's `append` since numpy creates new array each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused with syntax for [`np.append()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Use below for correct implementation:

```py
c = np.append(c,[a[i],b[k]])
```

Also for that you will get the output printed as:

```
[0. 3. 0. 4. 1. 3. 1. 4.]
```

I'm confused for the vector you are talking about : *([0 3][0 4][1 3][1 4])*

The representation stated by you is not a vector but seems as a matrix with dimension `4x2`, where [.reshape()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) might help you.

If you want that just write : `c.reshape((4,2))` which will get you:

```
[[0. 3.]
 [0. 4.]
 [1. 3.]
 [1. 4.]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it was just wrong... I talked about a vector but instead wanted to create a matrix.

Comment: @Felix No problem, you can give reshape() a try!

Comment: So now there occurred a problem with the reshape argument, maybe you have a solution for it. I now created an array (this time it's really an array, one dimensional with 100 entries) with this nested for-loops. And I now tried to reshape this (100,) vector into a (10,10) matrix. I tried it with `reshape` and also `np.reshape` but it keeps telling me: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (10,10). I have no idea why this array should be of size 1. The array has exactly 100 entries...

Comment: Edit: I solved it... Of course, I need to do the `reshape` outside of the for-loop otherwise Python tries to reshape the array in each loop.